# How to deal with Variable data over time in associations

Tags: data-modeling

In linked models (let's say a drink transaction, a waiter, and a restaurant), when you want to display data, you look for informations in your linked content :

*Where was that beer bought ?*

*Fetch Drink transaction => Fetch its Waiter => Fetch this waiter's Restaurant : this is where the beer was purchased*

So at time T, when I display all transactions, I fetch my data following associations, thus I can display this :

```
TransactionID   Waiter   Restaurant
1               Julius   Caesar's palace
2               Cleo     Moe's tavern
```

Let's say now that **my waiter is moved to another restaurant.**

If I refresh this table, the result will be

```
TransactionID   Waiter   Restaurant
1               Julius   Moe's tavern
2               Cleo     Moe's tavern
```

**But we know that the transaction n°1 was made in Caesar's palace !**

---

### Solution 1

Don't modify the waiter Julius, but clone it.

**Upside :** I keep an association between models, and still can filter with every field of every associated models.

**Downside :** Every modification on every model duplicates content, which can do a LOT when time passes.

### Solution 2

Keep a copy of the *current state* of your associated models when you create the transaction.

**Upside :** I don't duplicate the contents.

**Downside :** You can't anymore use *fields* on your content to display, sort or filter them, as your *original and real* data is inside, let's say, a JSON field. So you have to, if you use MySQL, filter your data by makin plain-search queries in that field.

---

What is your solution ?

---

[EDIT]

The problem goes further, as **it's not only a matter when association changes : a simple modification on an associated model causes a problem too**.
What I mean :

*What's the amount of this order ?*

*Fetch Drink transaction => Fetch its product => Fetch this product's Price => Multiply by order quantity : this is the total amount of the order*

So at time T, when I display all transactions, I fetch my data following associations, thus I can display this :

```
TransactionID   Qty   ProductId
1               2     1

ProductID   Title   Price
1           Beer    3
```

==> Amount of order n°1 : 6.

Let's say now that the beer costs 2,5.

If I refresh this table, the result will be

```
TransactionID   Qty   ProductId
1               2     1

ProductID   Title   Price
1           Beer    2,5
```

==> Amount of order n°1 : 5.

**So, once again, the 2 solutions are available : do I clone the beer product when its price is changed ? Do I save a copy of beer in my order when the order is made ? Do you have any third solution ?**

I can't just add an "amount" attribute on my orders : yes it can solve that problem (partially) but it's not a scalable solution as many other attributes will be in the same situation and I can't multiply attributes like this.

Comment: @Close Voters: I understand that this could be seen as opinion-based, but the actual question is "How can I save and retrieve historic data of associated objects?" and that can be answered objectively. The question just needs some rewording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Event Sourcing**

This is a good use case for [Event Sourcing](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). Martin Fowler wrote a very good article about it, I advise you to read it.

> there are times when we don't just want to see where we are, we also want to know how we got there.

The idea is to never overwrite data but instead create immutable transactions for everything you want to keep a history of. In your case you'll have `WaiterRelocationEvent`s and `PriceChangeEvent`s. You can recreate the status of any given time by applying every event in order.

If you don't use *Event Sourcing*, you lose information. Often it's acceptable to forget historic information, but sometimes it's not.

**Lambda Architecture**

As you don't want to recalculate everything on every single request, it's advisable to implement a [Lambda Architecture](http://lambda-architecture.net/). That architecture is often explained with BigData technology and frameworks, but you could implement it with Plain Old Java and CronJobs.

It consists of three parts: *Batch Layer*, *Service Layer* and *Speed Layer*.

The *Batch Layer* regularly calculates an aggregated version of the data, for example you'll calculate the monthly income once per day. So the current month's income will change every night until the month is over.

But now you want to know the income in real-time. Therefore you add a Speed Layer, which will apply all events of the current date immediately. Now if a request of the current month's income arrives, you'll add up the last result of the *Batch Layer* and the *Speed Layer*.

The *Service Layer* allows more advanced queries by combing multiple batch results and the *Speed Layer* results into one query. For example you can calculate the year's income by summing the monthly incomes.

But as said before, only use the Lambda approach if you need the data often and fast, because it adds extra complexity. Calculations which are rarely needed, should be run on-the-fly. For example: Which waiter creates the most income at Saturday evenings?

**Example**

```
Restaurants:
| Timestamp  | Id | Name            |
| ---------- | -- | --------------- |
| 2016-01-01 |  1 | Caesar's palace |
| 2016-11-01 |  2 | Moe's tavern    |

Waiters:
| Timestamp  | Id | Name     | FirstRestaurant |
| ---------- | -- | -------- | --------------- |
| 2016-01-01 | 11 | Julius   |               1 |
| 2016-11-01 | 12 | Cleo     |               2 |

WaiterRelocationEvents:
| Timestamp  | WaiterId | RestaurantId |
| ---------- | -------- | ------------ |
| 2016-06-01 |       11 |            2 |

Products:
| Timestamp  | Id | Name     | FirstPrice |
| ---------- | -- | -------- | ---------- |
| 2016-01-01 | 21 | Beer     |       3.00 |

PriceChangeEvent:
| Timestamp  | ProductId | NewPrice |
| ---------- | --------- | -------- |
| 2016-11-01 |        21 |     2.50 |

Orders:
| Timestamp  | Id | ProductId | Quantity | WaiterId |
| ---------- | -- | --------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2016-06-14 | 31 |        21 |        2 |       11 |
```

Now let's get all information about order 31.

1. get order 31
2. get price of product 21 at 2016-06-14

   - get last PriceChangeEvent before the date or use FirstPrice if none exists
3. calculate total price by multiplying retrieved price with quantity
4. get waiter 11
5. get waiter's restaurant at 2016-06-14

   - get last WaiterRelocationEvent before the date or use FirstRestaurant if none exists
6. get restaurant name by retrieved restaurant id of the waiter

As you can see it becomes complicated, therefore you should only keep history of useful data.

- I wouldn't involve the relocation events in the calculation. They could be stored, but I would store the restaurant id and the waiter id in the order directly.
- The price history on the other hand could be interesting to check if orders went down after a price change. Here you could use the *Lambda Architecure* to calculate a full order with prices from the raw order and the price history.

**Summary**

- Decide of which data you want to keep the history.
- Implement *Event Sourcing* for that data.
- Use the *Lambda Architecture* to speed up commonly used queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian. I will implement this solution as the lambda architecture seems particularily pertinent for my application (I need to fastly extract stats for restaurants), even if the part "_decide of which data you want to keep the history_" bothers me a bit : I would have prefered _not_ to have to choose.

Comment: @GregoryKapustin: If you have enough time to implement Event Sourcing for everything, you don't have to decide. But often you'll have to find a compromise. Another option would be to skip the batch layer. Save everything as event and calculate the current status in the speed layer alone (as in traditional applications), then run ad-hoc queries on events for historic data.

Answer (score 0):

I like the question as it raises something very straightforward and also something more subtle.

The common principle in both cases is that ‘History must not change’, meaning if we run a query over a specified past date range today the results are the same as when we run that same query at any point in the future.

**Waiters Case**

When a waiter changes restaurants we must not change the history of sales. If waiter Julius sells a drink yesterday in restaurant 1 then he switches to sell more drinks today in restaurant 2 we must retain those details.

Thus we want to be able to answer queries such as ‘how many drinks has Julius sold in restaurant 1’ and ‘how many drinks has Julius sold in all restaurants’.

To achieve this you have to abstract away from Julius as a waiter by bringing in a concept of staff. Julius is a member of staff. Staff work as waiters.  When working in restaurant 1 Julius is waiter A and when he works in another restaurant he is waiter B, but always the same member of staff – Julius.  With an entity ‘Staff’ the queries can be answered easily.

*Upside:* 
No loss of historic data or excessive duplications.

*Downside* New entity Staff must be managed. But waiter table content is reduced making net overhead of data storage is low.

In summary - abstract data subject to change into a new entity and refer back to it from transactions.

**Value of Order Case**

The extended use case regarding ‘what is the value of this order’ is more involved. I work in cross-currency transactions where value for the observer (user) in the price list changes from day to day as currency fluctuations occur.

But there are good reasons to lock the order value in place. For example invoice processing systems have tolerance for a small difference between their expected invoice value and that of the submitted invoice, but any large difference can lead to late payment whilst invoice handlers check the issue. Also, if customers run reports  on their historic purchases then the values of those orders must remain consistent despite fluctuations in currency rates over time.

The solution is to save into the order line:

1. the value of product in the customers currency,
2. or the rate between custom and supplier currency,
3. but ideally do both to avoid rounding errors.

What this does is provide a statement that ‘on the date that this order was placed line 1 cost $44.56 at exchange rate 1.1 $/£’.  Having this data locked in allows you to invoice to the customers expectation and provide consistent spend reports over time.

*Upside:* Consistent historic data. Fast database performance as no look-ups required against historic rate tables.

*Downside:* Some data duplication. However, trading off against overhead of storage and indexation for historic rate storage plus indexation then this is possibly an upside.

Regarding adding 'amount' to your order table - you have to do this if you want to achieve a consistent data history. If you only work in one currency then amount is the only additional storage concern. And by adding this one attribute you have protected history.  Your other alternative is to store a historic cost table for drinks so you know in January beer was $1, in February it as $1.10 etc  and then store the cost-table key in the transaction so that you can look up the cost if anyone asks about a historic order. But the overhead on storing the key PLUS the indexes needed to make this practicable will outweigh the storage cost of cloning 'amount' onto the order record.

In summary - clone cost data that will change over time.

Comment: Close to a mix of the 2 solutions I listed, I will need both a transition table like "staff" or "menu" (linking a bar and products), and some saving of important fields somewhere, in JSON format as I was saying, or other fields (i'll do it in an other model, like "orderData").

Still... I'm surprised that nowadays, we're stucked with these 2 solutions, both of which I don't find perfect... **(data growth + duplication of data + indexation of stringified or a lot of fields)**

Comment: If your app will have more than a few 10's of 1000's of records you need to be pragmatic. They make network faster and disk cheaper so the focus comes on to the decisions you take in database design that will eventually become the efficiency driving factors.